# Difference between types of Extend metamagic rods

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, metamagic

What is the difference between lesser extend, extend and greater extend, such as when creating a [Extend Metamagic Rod](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/metamagic-rods/metamagic-extend)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That defines which spell levels each [Rod](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods) can affect:

> Lesser and Greater Metamagic rods: Normal metamagic rods can be used with spells of 6th level or lower. Lesser rods can be used with spells of 3rd level or lower, while greater rods can be used with spells of 9th level or lower.

So, to sum it up:

- **Lesser Rod**: up to 3rd level spells;
- **Normal Rod**: up to 6th level spells;
- **Greater Rod**: up to 9th level spells.